# "He is a hero" or "He was a hero"?

Tags: conditionals, backshifting

Talking to someone who says

> What if my son is a hero!

would someone respond

> It would not surprise me if he **is**

Or would they respond

> It would not surprise me if he **was**

Comment: Both versions sound reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is possible.

The second in ungrammatical.

The third and most likely possibility is *It would surprise me if he were*.

Comment: All three versions would be fine.

Comment: @ErikKowal Yes,  *It wouldn’t surprise me if he was actually in the audience last night* would work, but good luck explaining it! I’m not going to try to teach a non-native speaker the nuance that would make the second one grammatical.  I have trouble teaching it to native speakers; I certainly don’t intend to do so with people who don’t even have a basic grasp of how to put these things together.

Comment: To an increasing number of native speakers, the second is perfectly grammatical and natural (and to quite a few, the subjunctive version is actually _ungrammatical_). While I agree with you that it's not grammatical to me, I wouldn't make blanket statements about its grammaticality to non-native speakers. (Note that most BrE speakers would likely not use the subjunctive here; AmE retains the distinction much more than BrE.)